# OpenCV on CentOS6 with Java installation problems

Tags: java, opencv, centos6

I am trying to install opencv2.4.9 on CentOS6 that I need to use in Java. After the entire trouble of finding all the dependent packages, I finally managed to get a positive result of cmake, saying: "configuring done, generating done". However, when I try to proceed with the make command, I get the following message: "make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop."

The cmake command I use is:

```
cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=NO ..
```

and the beginning of the output of it is:

```
-- Detected version of GNU GCC: 44 (404)
-- Could NOT find TIFF (missing:  TIFF_LIBRARY TIFF_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Could NOT find JPEG (missing:  JPEG_LIBRARY JPEG_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Could NOT find Jasper (missing:  JASPER_LIBRARIES JASPER_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- checking for module 'gstreamer-base-0.10'
--   package 'gstreamer-base-0.10' not found
-- checking for module 'libdc1394-2'
--   found libdc1394-2, version 2.1.2
-- checking for module 'libv4l1'
--   package 'libv4l1' not found
```

and it continues, so, at the very end, the output is:

```
--     Disabled:                    python world
--     Disabled by dependency:      -
--     Unavailable:                 androidcamera dynamicuda viz
--
--   GUI:
--     QT:                          NO
--     GTK+ 2.x:                    YES (ver 2.20.1)
--     GThread :                    YES (ver 2.26.1)
--     GtkGlExt:                    NO
--     OpenGL support:              NO
--     VTK support:                 NO
--
--   Media I/O:
--     ZLib:                        /usr/lib64/libz.so (ver 1.2.3)
--     JPEG:                        libjpeg (ver 62)
--     PNG:                         /usr/lib64/libpng.so (ver 1.2.49)
--     TIFF:                        build (ver 42 - 4.0.2)
--     JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 1.900.1)
--     OpenEXR:                     build (ver 1.7.1)
--
--   Video I/O:
--     DC1394 1.x:                  NO
--     DC1394 2.x:                  YES (ver 2.1.2)
--     FFMPEG:                      NO
--       codec:                     NO
--       format:                    NO
--       util:                      NO
--       swscale:                   NO
--       gentoo-style:              NO
--     GStreamer:                   NO
--     OpenNI:                      NO
--     OpenNI PrimeSensor Modules:  NO
--     PvAPI:                       NO
--     GigEVisionSDK:               NO
--     UniCap:                      NO
--     UniCap ucil:                 NO
--     V4L/V4L2:                    YES/YES
--     XIMEA:                       NO
--     Xine:                        NO
--
--   Other third-party libraries:
--     Use IPP:                     NO
--     Use Eigen:                   NO
--     Use TBB:                     NO
--     Use OpenMP:                  NO
--     Use GCD                      NO
--     Use Concurrency              NO
--     Use C=:                      NO
--     Use Cuda:                    NO
--     Use OpenCL:                  YES
--
--   OpenCL:
--     Version:                     dynamic
--     Include path:                /root/opencv-2.4.9/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2                                           
--     Use AMD FFT:                 NO
--     Use AMD BLAS:                NO
--
--   Python:
--     Interpreter:                 /usr/local/python-2.6.6/bin/python (ver 1.4)
--
--   Java:
--     ant:                         /usr/bin/ant (ver 1.7.1)
--     JNI:                         /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64/include           /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64/include/linux /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64/include                                                                                   
--     Java tests:                  YES
--
--   Documentation:
--     Build Documentation:         NO
--     Sphinx:                      NO
--     PdfLaTeX compiler:           NO
--
--   Tests and samples:
--     Tests:                       YES
--     Performance tests:           YES
--     C/C++ Examples:              YES
--
--   Install path:                  /usr/local
--
--   cvconfig.h is in:              /root/opencv-2.4.9
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------
--
CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:1054 (message):
The source directory is the same as binary directory.  "make clean" may
damage the source tree


-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /root/opencv-2.4.9
```

I run cmake in a build folder which I create in the opencv-2.4.9 folder. After cmake, I try to run make, but it gives me the above-mentioned error. I don't know how to continue because I don't know where I am making an error. Some hints will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the makefile was in the parent folder, so I just run make in that folder.